# Is a vector space's basis a generating set?

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, vector-spaces

All vector spaces are groups. Since a vector space is defined by its basis, is it sensible to consider a basis a generating set in the context of a group?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, not as a group. How would you make $(0.5,0,0)\in\Bbb R^3$ from the standard basis elements? Remember that multiplication by $\frac12$ is not a group operation in this case.

The additional structure you gain from scalar multiplication with $\Bbb R$ makes $\Bbb R^3$ into what's called an *$\Bbb R$-module*. Vector spaces are special cases of modules. In general, given a ring $A$, an $A$-module is an abelian group $G$ (written additively) whose elements may be multiplied by the elements of $A$ to make other elements in $G$. This multiplication is required to work nicely with the ring operations of $A$ (associative, distributive, and so on).